# angularjs fullcalendar eventclick scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, fullcalendar

i have a controller named CalendarDemoCtrl where i have the config for fullcalendar as shown below.

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            height: 600,
            editable: false,
            locale:'es',
            //navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            businessHours: true, // display business hours
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotLabelFormat : 'h:mm a',
            timeFormat: 'h:mm a',
            navLinks: true,
            navLinkDayClick: function(date, jsEvent) {
                cc['mycalendar'].fullCalendar('changeView','agendaDay');
                cc['mycalendar'].fullCalendar('gotoDate',date);
                $scope.currentDate = cc['mycalendar'].fullCalendar("getView").title;
           },

            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            slotDuration: '00:15:00',
            header: false,  // remove default toolbar
            //editable: true,   
            eventRender: $scope.eventRender,
            eventClick : $scope.onEventClick
            //dayClick : $scope.onEventClick
        }
    }
```

and in the same  controller i have defined $scope.onEventClick and $scope.addEvent.

```
$scope.addEvent = function() {

        $rootScope.oldFormData = $.extend( true, {}, $scope.formData );

        $scope.entroModal = true;
        $scope.modalOpen('new');
    };
$scope.onEventClick = function(index) {


        $scope.formData = $.extend( true, {}, index.cita );
        var date_inicio = new Date(index.cita.inicio) ;
        $scope.formData.inicio = date_inicio.getDate() + "/" + ( date_inicio.getMonth() + 1) + "/"+ date_inicio.getFullYear()+ " " + date_inicio.getHours()+ ":" + (date_inicio.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + date_inicio.getMinutes();
        var date_fin = new Date(index.cita.fin) ;
        $scope.formData.fin = date_fin.getDate() + "/" + ( date_fin.getMonth() + 1) + "/"+ date_fin.getFullYear()+ " " + date_fin.getHours()+ ":" + (date_fin.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + date_fin.getMinutes();
        $.extend( $scope.formData , $rootScope.oldFormData );
        $scope.modalOpen('edit');
    };
```

First one is used with a button when an user wants to add an event and second one is to edit an event in the calendar. However when adding an event the scope goes to an scope lower than eventclick so when i add events it displays in the calendar when i click and edit the event the event is not modified in the calendar as it is an scope above.

1. $rootscope: id 1
2. $scope: id 10 (this is eventclick works)
3. child $scope: id 11 (this is addevent works)

this is total mess and i'm confuse how this happened and how can i have both events within the same scope? please advise thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unsure why this happens and how to permanent fix it but my workaround was to broadcast an event and make sure when listening ot it, it has the same scope.